Load external .json file and merge it with structured hydra config
I am creating some scripts using python and I wanted to utilize Hydra (https://hydra.cc/). I am following the structured config pattern, where I have a config.py and config.yaml in a conf directory, and I am validating my config using dataclasses, for example:
#### config.yaml

visualisation_conf:
  degradation:
    data_path: /measurements
    input_data_formats: .csv

#### config.py

@dataclass
class VisualisationConfig:
    degradation: DegradationConfig

@dataclass
class DegradationConfig:
    data_path: str
    input_data_formats: str

@dataclass
class MainHydraConfig:
    visualisation_conf: VisualisationConfig


#### Usage in script:
import hydra
from conf.config import MainHydraConfig

@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../conf", config_name="config")
def main(base_cfg: MainHydraConfig):
    input_type = base_cfg.visualisation_conf.degradation.input_data_formats
    ...

This worked fine, until I needed to load a json file and add it to my configuration. I have an external json file (called "schema.json" and residing in conf directory) that I would like to load at runtime and merge with my main config. I have tried something like this:
#### config.yaml

dataset_schema:
  schema_path: ${hydra:runtime.cwd}/conf/schema.json
  schema: ...

#### config.py

@dataclass
class JSONSchemaConfig:
    schema_path: str
    schema: dict = field(default_factory=dict)

    def load_schema(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.schema_path):
            with open(self.schema_path, "r") as f:
                self.schema = json.load(f)


@dataclass
class MainHydraConfig:
    json_schema: JSONSchemaConfig = field(default_factory=JSONSchemaConfig)

    def __post__init__(self):
        self.json_schema.load_schema()
        merged_conf = OmegaConf.create(self.json_schema.schema)
        OmegaConf.merge(self, merged_conf)

however, nothing is being loaded at runtime, as the __post_init__ is not being called. Is what I want to achieve even possible in OmegaConf/Hydra? Maybe I should try a different approach for my end goal, that is, loading a json file as dict and merging it with rest of the configuration? I know I can move the logic related to loading this json to the script itself, but I am pretty sure I am just missing some small detail that prevents this from working as expected.
22/7/24 EDIT
As per @Daraan answer, I tried to use 'hydra.experimental.callbacks'. I modified Daraan's answer and added parts from documentation (found here: https://hydra.cc/docs/experimental/callbacks/), now it looks like this:
#### conf/hydra/callbacks/load_json_schema_callback.yaml

# @package _global_
hydra:
  callbacks:
    load_json_schema_callback:
      _target_: conf.config.ParseJsonCallback


#### conf/config.yaml
defaults:
  - /hydra/callbacks:
      - load_json_schema_callback


dataset_schema:
  schema_path: [conf,schema.json]
  schema: ???


#### conf/config.py

@dataclass
class JSONSchemaConfig:
    schema_path: str
    schema: dict = field(default_factory=dict)

    def load_schema(self):
        cwd = hydra.core.hydra_config.HydraConfig.get().runtime.cwd
        _schema_path: str = os.path.join(cwd, *self.schema_path)

        if os.path.exists(_schema_path):
            with open(_schema_path, "r") as f:
                self.schema = json.load(f)

class ParseJsonCallback(Callback):
    def on_job_start(
        self, config: DictConfig, *, task_function: TaskFunction, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> None:
        JSONSchemaConfig.load_schema(config.dataset_schema)


When I debug this code, while I am inside the 'load_schema', or even in the 'on_job_start' function (frame), the json is loaded properly. When I leave those frames and go back to the main script, the value in the main config is is '???' again.

The dataclasses are only for schema backing and duck-typing. While it looks like a MainHydraConfig class it is actually a DictConfig without any functionality of the schema classes.
If you want to call the __post_init__ function you actually need to create on of the real MainHydraConfig classes.
As a solution, you could write an extra function that takes care of it. I think with the below function the __post_init__ is not necessary.
@dataclass
class MainHydraConfig:
   ...

   @staticmethod
   def postprocess(settings : omegaconf.DictConfig):
      """
      insert the settings.json_schema : DictConfig as self
      and replaces the settings.json_schema.schema node
      """
      JSONSchemaConfig.load_schema(settings.json_schema) 

# ----

@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="../conf", config_name="config")
def main(base_cfg: MainHydraConfig):
   MainHydraConfig.postprocess(base_cfg)

   # obv you could also use the one liner directly, but imo a descriptive name sounds better.
   # JSONSchemaConfig.load_schema(base_cfg.json_schema) 



If you really want to use the __post_init__ you could use
OmegaConf.create(OmegaConf.to_object(base_cfg)) # -> real MainHydraConfig -> DictConfig, as one of many possible ways.
You could pack everything into a decorator to keep your main function more clean https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/decorating_main/
@hydra.main(...)
@postproces # write decorator that takes care of parsing and inserting the json file
def main(base_cfg): 

(Edit Hydra only) - use a callback for postprocessing
To modify the config and have no extra python code the only other way I see is by using callbacks. Note: If you run your script remote or with multirun check that you set up the callback correctly.
from config import JSONSchemaConfig
from hydra.experimental.callback import Callback

class ParseJsonCallback(Callback):
   
    def on_job_start(self, config: DictConfig, *, task_function: TaskFunction, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """
        Called in both RUN and MULTIRUN modes, once for each Hydra job (before running application code).
        The `task_function` argument is the function
        decorated with `@hydra.main`.
        """
        # modify the config
        JSONSchemaConfig.load_schema(config.json_schema) 


To execute the callback register it, eg. by adding
# conf.yaml

hydra:
    callbacks:
       insert_json:
          _target_ : <modules to>.ParseJsonCallback


So there would be no way to decouple this post-processing from application? This would require me to change how I use the config everywhere (which is not that big of a problem, but one would think Hydra allows for something like this)

You could write your own decorator that takes care of it @hydra.main(...)@hydra_postprocess. However, I think I now see a pure way, I'll edit it in.

You probably considered it, but how about copying the .json files and keep it as a yaml side by side?

@KrzysiekDD I added a way how you can do it from the hydra side via callbacks.

I tried this method, and it works up to some point. The json is loaded and its value is set to the dictionary I wanted, however after its set, the value in the main script gets set back to the placeholder ('???' in config.yaml). Do I need to merge the newly loaded file with the original config, or could this be an error in how I couple my code?. Edited the question to include the latest version

OmegaConf.merge() operates on OmegaConf configs. in some cases it converts the input to OmegaConf configs using OmegaConf.create().
It does not change the inputs, instead if returns a merged config object.
It will certainly not modify your dataclass instance directly.
Your design seems incompatible.
